# Advanced Custom Fields not populating on page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, child-theming

I followed the ACF documentation code example for inserting custom fields onto the page, but haven't had any luck seeing it actually display. I'm new to php so I'd love another set of eyes on this.

I inserted this code:

```
<div class="date_effective"><!-- date effective -->
    <?php if( get_field('date_effective') ):?>
    <?php echo get_field('date_effective'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

into the content.php file within my theme, which is a child theme of WP Bootstrap Starter.

Comment: depends on how your data is saved, and if you are in the loop. Like, if you have saved it on an options page, you need to pass `'option'` as a second parameter - If you are outside the loop, then you need to pass the post object or ID as a second parameter. etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The php code looks correct but I would try making sure a couple things.

1. 'date_effective' has a value by printing it prior to the if statement - you can also use "the_field('date_effective')" to print to the field to the screen.
2. Make sure the field isn't blank on your WordPress page. Sometimes if you add information to a field and then change the field type or aspects it will remove the data from the field.